# LDAPS on Windows Server 2012 R2 without CA

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, certificate

I am building Splunk in a production environment.  The long and short is, in order to get relevant AD things that I need from my Domain Controllers, which are running Windows Server 2012 R2, I need to enable LDAPS.  LDAPS cannot be created using a Certificate Authority, for many reasons (cost, CA's cannot be on Domain Controllers, etc).

So, the nitty gritty is, I need to enable LDAPS on our domain controller, **without** using a CA.  I have a Mac, and have used OpenSSL in the past, but I don't know how to do this.   I have found a related link here, however I am a bit confused and need some clarity.

https://kostya.ws/projects/windows/ldaps-on-server-2008-r2-without-ca/

If anyone can help me out, add more insight, anything at all, I would appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [link]http://www.javaxt.com/tutorials/windows/how_to_enable_ldaps_in_active_directory[/link]


This actually seems to be very helpful, trying this process now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your terminology is a little confused. As long as you're using certificates, you'll always have a CA somewhere whether it's your own or a 3rd party's. The first step in your [javaxt.com link](http://www.javaxt.com/tutorials/windows/how_to_enable_ldaps_in_active_directory) is even "Create a Certificate Authority"

What I believe you meant to ask was how to configure LDAPS in Active Directory without running a Windows-based CA. And the previously mentioned link describes exactly how to do that using OpenSSL. The high level steps are:

- Create a CA
- Install/Trust your CA cert on all your clients
- Generate a cert for your DC(s)
- Install the cert(s) on your DC(s)
- Reboot

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry for my novice questions, but I followed the step by step and used LDAP Admin to test the LDAP over SSL, (Firewall port is open) and winevent log produces this: http://imgur.com/xGZ5F2g

Does this mean the private key needs to be added to the root of the machine?  I'm not sure how to interpret that. 

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: In step 3 where you generated the CSR, the private key is also generated silently in the background and stored in the Windows cert store for that computer.  In step 5 where you accept the signed certificate, did you run that command with the signed cert on the same computer you generated the CSR?  If not, that's your problem.  If you need additional help with this process, I'd recommend starting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for Splunk, or just within your own domain for domain-joined and enterprise-controlled devices, you can use a self-signed certficate for LDAPS; it's just a matter of enrolling the certificate in your specific devices so that they will trust it.